# Applying to graduate school after the deadline

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I was about to submit my application to one of my top choices for graduate school (PhD) and realized that the deadline was Dec 15.
Somehow I confused the PhD deadline (Dec 15) with the MS deadline (Jan 15).
Should I still submit my application?

Comment: You should contact someone at the school in question and ask them.  The default answer would be "no", but just in case they would be willing to accept it for some reason, they are the only ones from whom you could find that out.

Comment: I missed a deadline and asked to submit a few days late and it was fine since they hadn't even sent the applications to the professors yet (hence the reviewers didn't even know my app was late).  I agree with @NateEldredge just ask and see if you can still send it in.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be rejected, but if it costs nothing but effort, then you may as well. I doubt there would be any lasting effect if you want to re-apply in the next cycle.